# Setting anchor stops resizing of Windows Form

Tags: c#, resize, anchor

I have a form with several controls. As soon as I add a "Bottom" anchor to a button on my form, I am no longer able to resize the form to be smaller on the vertical axis. I can still resize it to be bigger. The same thing happens in the horizontal direction once I add a "Right" anchor to any of my visible controls. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AutoSize member on the form was set to True. Set this to false.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to repro your situation, but the result is opposite. I'm able to resize the form ! Hence, I have some suggestions for you:

1. Have you set the FormBorderStyle to Sizable yet?
2. Set the MinimumSize to 0,0.

Cheers.